# "unresolved external symbol" error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pointers

Please have a look at the following code

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

**Magic.h**

```
#pragma once

class Magic
{
public:
    Magic();
    ~Magic();
    virtual void display()=0;
};
```

**Spell.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Magic.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Spell :
    public Magic
{
public:
    Spell(void);
    Spell(string words);
    ~Spell(void);
    void display();

private:
    string words;
};
```

**Spell.cpp**

```
#include "Spell.h"
#include "Magic.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



Spell::Spell(void)
{
}

Spell::Spell(string words)
{
    this->words = words;
}


Spell::~Spell(void)
{
    cout << "Delete Spell" << endl;
}

void Spell::display()
{
    cout << "Spell Words: " << words << endl;
}
```

Here, I am getting the error

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Revision1_1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Spell.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Magic::~Magic(void)" (??1Magic@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??0Spell@@QAE@XZ$0
1>Spell.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Magic::Magic(void)" (??0Magic@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Spell::Spell(void)" (??0Spell@@QAE@XZ)
1>C:\Users\yohan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Revision1_1\Debug\Revision1_1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I do not understand what to do here. Why is this happening? Please help! I am new to C++ anyway..

Comment: It's redundant to include the same headers you include in a .h file in a .cpp file and slows compiles down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't implement

```
Magic();
~Magic();
```

You'll need to either implement them inline, in an implementation file, or mark them `= default`.

Comment: OK. But how to? This is the first time I am dealing with abstract classes

Comment: @Sepala you can just write `{}` after you declare the methods.

Comment: @Sepala: Abstract classes are no different from regular classes in this regard. It is only the pure-virtual functions of an abstract class that don't need an implementation.

Answer (score 3):

`Magic` is not implementing its constructor and destructor (which also should be `virtual`).

Don't even declare the constructor if not necessary, e.g.

```
class Magic {
public:
  virtual ~Magic() {}
  virtual void display() = 0;
};
```

Unrelated: I didn't know you can display magic.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared a destructor in your `Magic` class but did not define it. That's why the linker complains (and the compiler doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an implementation for Magic.  If your intention is for Magic to be an abstract base class, then just change its declaration to:

```
#pragma once

class Magic
{
public:
    virtual void display()=0;
};
```

Remember, any method that is not followed by = 0 in the interface must be implemented in the class.